# Using 'this' within added functions to the variable with set selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say, I have variable which has been set to the desired selector. Then, to keep code clean I add function to that variable. So, is this a good idea to access original variable with linked selector within that function and access function that I may add in the future by using 'this'. If there a better way to accomplish it, please go ahead, I'd like to know it.

```
var elementzero = $('.element-class');

elementzero.initialize = function() {
    // is there possible to access elementzero selector by 'this'
    $(this).addClass('loaded');

    // and call elementzero.someFunction using the same 'this'
    this.someFunction();
}

elementzero.someFunction = function() {
    console.log('someFunction');
}

elementzero.initialize();
```

Comment: Yes that works. That's how JavaScript works in general. Note that you don't need to use `$(this)`, since `this` is already a jQuery object. Just use `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to add ad-hoc functions to your jQuery object like that. It's best to keep jQuery and your layer separate.

Perhaps you could define a controller object like this:

```
var elementzero = $('.element-class');
var controller = {
    initialize: function() {
        elementzero.addClass('loaded');
        controller.someFunction();
    },
    someFunction: function() {
        console.log('someFunction');
    }
};

controller.initialize();
```

You also may want to look into a JavaScript framework to help you structure your code.

Comment: At the very least, if adding a jQuery function, structure it like a plugin on the `$.fn` object...

Comment: @War10ck Using `$.fn` I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink But, may I ask, why is this a bad idea to use `ad-hoc` functions.

Comment: @Katherine as your code base grows if you keep on adding ad-hoc functions onto your jQuery instance it may become difficult to remember exactly what comes from jQuery and what is just for that particular instance. Your code will also be more re-usable if you put your own functions in a separate place where they can be invoked by other jQuery instances

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink But what about if I add selector variable inside that controller, that way controller will be fully related to specific task, or it is the same idea.

Comment: @Katherine that could work sure. It would still highly recommend checking out a JavaScript framework to help organize your code...that would be a quick huge win for future maintenance. Here's a good starting point to see what's out there: http://todomvc.com/